# Do SVG docs support custom data- attributes?

Tags: svg, web-standards

In HTML5, elements can have arbitrary metadata stored in XML attributes whose names start with `data-` such as `<p data-myid="123456">`.  Is this part of the SVG spec too?

In practice this technique works fine for SVG docs in many places.  But I'd like to know if it's part of the official SVG spec or not, because the format is young enough that there's still a lot of incompatibility between browsers, especially in mobile.  So before committing to code I'd like know if I can expect future browsers to converge on supporting this.

I found [this message](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2011May/0014.html) from the working group mailing list saying they "expect [they] will" support it.  Did this become official?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

While other answers are technically correct, they omit the fact that SVG provides an alternative mechanism for `data-*`. SVG [allows any attribute and tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html#ForeignNamespaces) to be included, as long as it doesn't conflict with existing ones (in other words: you should use namespaces).

To use this (equivalent) mechanism:

- use `mydata:id` instead of `data-myid`, like this: `<p mydata:id="123456">`
- make sure you define the namespace in SVG opening tag, like this: `<svg xmlns:mydata="http://www.myexample.com/whatever">`

---

**EDIT:** [SVG2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/), currently W3C Candidate Recommendation (04 October 2018), will [support `data-` directly](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#DataAttributes) (without namespaces, the same as HTML). It will take some time before the support is widespread though. Thanks @cvrebert for [pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30519648/593487).

Comment: Third part of the equation: `el.getAttribute('mydata:id')` to get the data you attached to the SVG element. (Note: if you're using d3, the namespace will be stripped by default and you'll just `el.getAttribute('id')`.)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. SVG is an extension of XML which allows you to use tags from different namespaces.

Comment: Why does the namespace have to be custom? Why wouldn't declaring an HTML5 namespace in the document be enough to use `data-*` in SVG?

Comment: FYI, whether using a private namespace (e.g.: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:mydata="http://www.myexample.com/whatever"><text x="10" y="20" mydata:id="something">SVG</text></svg>`) or the xhtml namespace, neither will validate on https://validator.w3.org/check (using SVG 1.1), but both do work in the browser. It's then possible to use either `getAttribute` or `getAttributeNS` to fetch the data.

Comment: Is there a way to make the validator happy? Does the response from "http://www.myexample.com/whatever" have to be some specific content?

Answer (score 30):

The [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) is part of HTML5. It’s not a generic XML attribute.

The current SVG W3C Recommendation is [SVG 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/) (from 2011-08). It doesn’t allow this attribute, as you can check in the [attributes list](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-SVG11-20110816/attindex.html).

The [same](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-SVG2-20120828/attindex.html) is the case for the [SVG 2 Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-SVG2-20120828/) (from 2012-08). **Update (2015)**: It seems that [it’s intended](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/track/actions/3694) to support `data-*` attributes in [SVG 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/) (currently still a Working Draft).

Answer (score 18):

`data-*` attributes on SVG elements are officially supported in the current draft of SVG2. See:

- [`w3c/svgwg` commit `1cb4ee9`: Added `SVGElement.dataset` and allowed `data-*` attributes on all SVG elements.](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/commit/1cb4ee9e165b3d777d33828da8fa757e67d019ff)
- [ACTION-3694: Add "data-*" attributes notes to spec.](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/track/actions/3694) (Created on: January 15, 2015)
- [RESOLUTION: We will reserve "data-*" attributes to be used in SVG content. The API for handling them is on Element.](http://www.w3.org/2015/01/15-svg-minutes.html#item03) (from SVG WG Telecon on 15-Jan-2015)
- https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/2014Dec/0022.html

Answer (score 10):

there is a more general mechanism.

svg supports `desc` elements which may contain arbitrary xml from other namespaces. link instances of this elements or child nodes from you own namespace by dependent ids or refid attributes.

[this is the relevant part of the spec (5.4)](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#DescriptionAndTitleElements).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Should I infer SVG doesn't officially support `data-` attributes?

Comment: Isn't `desc` meant for accessibility sakes?

Comment: @matt I don't think so, at least based On the stabndard.

Comment: @matt Not necessarily. Afaik the standard would only mention the purpose of annotation independent of any rendering. This doesn't contradict the element's suitability for the purpose. Specifically, there is [a blog post](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2013/12/using-aria-enhance-svg-accessibility/) discussing the use of `aria-labelledby` attributes and desc elements as accessible labels. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/desc) recommends a similar use. given the plethora of google results, best practices for accessible svg might be worth a question of its own,

Comment: +1. Although johndodo's suggestion (using a custom namespace) can be better at providing a dataset-like feature, it is an XML feature rather than SVG's.   

Using `desc` would be easier for a general purpose comment.

Comment: @RockyRoad: not really - SVG specification explicitly allows such attributes (as opposed to for instance HTML/XHTML which doesn't). Also note that while you can (mis)use `desc`ription elements for arbitrary data it is (IMHO) quite obvious from the link that this was not the intended purpose of the `desc` element. Not saying you shouldn't do it, just that there is a better way.