# How to add desc elements using d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I want to show tooltips on mouseover in an svg chart. The tooltip itself will have html elements with data from the moused over svg element interpolated into it. To store the values that will be interpolated, I want to use 'desc' elements for each of the svg elements (as pointed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15569558/751002 ). These desc elements will contain the values needed for interpolating into the tooltip. Now, how do I append these desc elements  using d3.js, for example, to arrive at the following structure:

```
<circle class="show-tooltip" cx="-7" cy="0" r="7">
  <desc xmlns:mydoc="http://example.org/mydoc">
    <mydoc:title>This is an example SVG file</mydoc:title>
    <mydoc:para>The global description uses markup from the 
    <mydoc:emph>mydoc</mydoc:emph> namespace.</mydoc:para>
  </desc>
</circle>
```

Thanks,
mano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic structure of the D3 code would be this.

```
var desc = element.append("circle")
  // set attributes
  .append("desc")
  .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

desc.append("mydoc:title").html("This is an example SVG file");
desc.append("mydoc:para").html("The global description uses markup from the <mydoc:emph>mydoc</mydoc:emph> namespace.");
```

Comment: To add to Lars' reply, if you want to do this for many elements, you can use the [`each()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each) method on your selection.  For example, if you have your circles as a d3 selection, you would use: `circles.each(function(d,i){ var desc = d3.select(this).append("desc"); /* and then the rest of Lars' code */ });`.

Comment: You don't even need this -- you could simply do `circles.append("desc");` etc. This will automatically append `desc` elements to each element in the `circles` selection.

Comment: Of course.  I was thinking that you'd need the `each` so that you could access the data variables to set the descriptive content.  But the `<desc>` element will automatically inherit the data from the circle that it is appended to.  So you could do `desc = circles.append("desc").attr(/*namespace*/);` and then `desc.append("mydoc:title").html(function(d){ return d.title;})` to fill the description for each circle with content from the appropriate data object.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I try to add the 'xmlns:xhtml' attr like `.attr("xmlns:xhtml", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")` I get the following error: `Uncaught NamespaceError: An attempt was made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces.`

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can (or should need to) specify namespaces for attributes. Do you want to do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Xva5j/)?

Comment: Using the latest example given by Manokaran, this should be sufficient:    
    `.attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")`
And there is really no need to add any namespace prefix to any of the children. All descendants will inherit the namespace of the parent.

Comment: As far as I can tell, browsers just don't give a flying F! about namespaces when parsing a `<!DOCTYPE html>` doc.  I get the same error when trying to specify a named namespace, even though the format is exactly as given in the examples in the [SVG `<metadata>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/metadata.html) spec.  So then I tried [this experiment](http://jsfiddle.net/Xva5j/3/) with the same code three times, hard-coded vs dynamic, named NS vs default.  When I query the namespace, I get the xhtml namespace for the hard-coded versions and the svg namespace for the dynamic version. ???

Comment: But regardless, @FernOfTheAndes suggestion is valid XML (important if you want to save the images as stand-alone SVG) that doesn't cause errors for the html parser, so I'd go with that.

Comment: Thanks LarsKotthoff, FernOfTheAndes, AmeliaBR. Your suggestion solved my problem. If the original answer is updated I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Updated. Is it what you're looking for now?