# svg inline in HTML5 and svg custom attribute

Tags: html, svg, dtd, w3c-validation, custom-attribute

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<body>
<svg version="1.1" id="svg1" data-kind="myvalue"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

When I tried to validate the code above on w3 site, I recieved the error below.

> Error: Attribute data-kind not allowed on element svg at this point.
>   ...svg version="1.1" id="svg1" data-kind="button">

How can I write a custom attribute in html5 for inline SVG and how can I create a custom namespace or dtd. I will be approciated if you can show and example or tutorial. I will be waiting for your help about how to solve this problem.

Comment: That are at least three questions in one which is much too broad. What is the main problem?

Comment: The main problem is my custom attribute isn't validation.

Comment: Why is that a problem though?

Comment: There is no problem at runtime. however, I would like to code in web standards. and the w3c validator warns me about it.

Comment: That's because it's not a known attribute. There's not much you can do about it though. You can't create custom namespaces in html, only in xml or xhtml.

Comment: Thank you for reply. so how do I do it with xhtml. Could you give an example?

Comment: use xmlns to define the namespace and then your-namespace:attribute to use it.

Answer (score 4):

In HTML5, [`svg`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/embedded-content-0.html#svg) is an element from the [SVG namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/infrastructure.html#svg-namespace).

So it is not an HTML element.

Thus you can’t use attributes that are defined for HTML elements only, among them the [custom `data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) or [Microdata](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/56670/17633) attributes etc.

It’s also [not possible to use `data-*` attributes *inside* of SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580322/1591669) documents.