# Is there any way to make an SVG object clickable?

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm working with the SVG that can be viewed here: http://n1t2.info/

I would just post the SVG, but because of the street maps layer the file is extremely large. However, you can see if you click the link that it's a map divided into 18 different svg paths, with a number of different colors shading them.  My goal with this map is to make each of the 18 different sections clickable, or be able to give them an `<a href="example.com">`.  Is this possible with SVGs at all?

edit: A comment suggested a show the way that I'm constructing the SVG file.  You can see my method for that [here.](https://github.com/ntucker1/DSWP2/blob/master/censusColorMap)

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you're drawing the svg image?

Comment: Did so! Thanks @MilesGrimes

Comment: Are you able to edit the `<path>` element manually? So you can asign an `id="zone1"` for each zone?

Comment: Yes indeed, @Frondor . In fact, that's how I originally wrote the code to change the fill depending on the income info for that area :-)

Comment: I have a solution but it is based on jquery.. is it ok for you to use jquery or you prefer just pure javascript?

Comment: At this point, I'll take anything that can get the job done! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, the best solution is the SVG [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a) element.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <a xlink:href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532371/do-svg-docs-support-custom-data-attributes">

    <path d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z" fill="orange" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"></path>

  </a>

</svg>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, @Kaiido!

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it pretty easily by adding a `data` attribute to each `<path>` element and then handle it via jquery or just javascript.

1. First, add something like `data-url="http://your-url.com"` to the
   `<path>` element. Example: `<path data-url="http://your-url.com">`.
2. Add jquery library just before the closing of your `</body>` tag, and the script in step #3 just like:

   ```
                   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                   <script>
                           //your script
                   </script>
           </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. instead of `//your script` you'll paste this one:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
           $('path').on('click', function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               var url = $(this).data('url');
               console.log('Moving to:', url);
               window.open(url, '_blank');
           });
   });
   ```
4. Test it: http://jsfiddle.net/jpvu852d/

Comment: @n1c9 In case you are trying to implement this question **before** my last edit, please take a look at the code, it changed a bit :) I hope you  know how to deal with javascript libraries like jquery

Comment: I know a little here and there :-) but thanks for giving me another excuse to learn more, and thanks for the great answer!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532371/do-svg-docs-support-custom-data-attributes

Answer (score 0):

A search on google turned up this jQuery plugin for decorating image maps that may help you achieve your goal:

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?what.html