# Attribute in dom but not usable in a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-selectors

I face a very weird situation here.
For the context I'm using a modified version of [this svg-edit fork](http://editor.method.ac/) and I needed to add custom html attributes (data-propzone="true").
But the weird thing is when I load my svg with the svg-edit "setSvgString" function, I can't use my attribute as a selector, you can see in the screenshot that I can use the element ID or even the fill value and it's working fine, it retrieve my element with my custom attribute but with `$('[data-propzone="true"]')` the result is empty...
[image: Javascript console]

My element with my custom attribute is in the dom as you can see:
[image]

I really don't know what could be wrong here, I always use data-attributes selectors and never had an issue.

I'm sorry you can't reproduce it in the demo page because I had to make a modification to allow custom attributes to be added so you can't reproduce this issue, I hope the screenshot will be enough, if someone as a lead to help me understand it will be a great help !

Comment: Did you read this [Do SVG docs support custom data- attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532371/do-svg-docs-support-custom-data-attributes)

Comment: @jcubic The OP doesn't seem to be using the data- API, he has an attribute that's compatible with that API but he's not using the API itself to get the data, just a CSS attribute selector which should work in theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

```
var arr = $('*').filter(function () {
   return $(this).attr('data-propzone') === "true"; 
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: It does not work.
I adapted your code a little with $("*") instead of $(document).children() and you can see the issue here...
http://i.imgur.com/wTWVx0Q.png
If the attribute is added it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

What if you try like this `$('*[data-propzone="true"]')` ?

Comment: What is weird here is that if I add an attribute AFTER the svg is "loaded" in the editor, it's working.
You can see it here:
http://imgur.com/RogErdm